WebView scroll stop working after showing modal sheet inside the site
I'm using accompanist WebView. Also I tried use standard webView with AndroidView - it nothing change at all
When I click on item which opens modal sheet inside the site both vertical and horisontal scrolls stop working.
I tried call after this webView invalidate, requestLayout, reload, loadUrl. Also I check that webView continue receiving move actions. I inspected the site in Chrome inspector - it's all right. And the problem with not working scroll only appears in webView
Only one thing can temporary fix this scroll. If I go to other screen and then go back to webView screen, webView recreates and that fixes scroll
Why this happenes? How can I start webView without broken scroll after showing bottom modal sheet inside the site?

The problem was caused by a fake click. I should have added an up click after the down click
